# Pressing the href link has no action

Tags: html, css, href, extend

I use this script to create a pull down box, works perfectly excepting a single thing. If i add a link in that box, pressing it will result in no action. Shortly the links don't work in this script.
Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Script:

```
 function prepareList() {
     $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
         .click(function (event) {
             if (this == event.target) {
                 $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
                 $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
             }
             return false;
         })
         .addClass('collapsed')
         .children('ul').hide();
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    prepareList()
});
```

Comment: What is the Error Console?

Comment: Can you tell where have you placed the href?

Comment: You mean `<li><a href="url">link</a></li>` inside `#expList` don't move you to the url?

Comment: True form: `<a href="url">Click</a>`, wrong form: `<a href="http://www.google.com">Click</a>`

Comment: OK i will see to it and teell you if possible.

Comment: This is where I used the script: http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/index/tsc/0-25 if you press the + button you will see a random link which has its target to google.com, but it doesn't work

Comment: Does anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler is trapping the click on the URL and the "return false" is cancelling it.

Try removing the false.. not sure you need it in this implementation..

Andrew

Comment: Worked, just that not the way it was supposed to do. Instead of replacing the whole link in the address bar, it adds it after the page link. Check: http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/index/tsc/0-25